# 2D barcode PDF417. What encoding or method to use that can split two byte characters into ASCII characters?

Tags: c#, encoding, barcode, pdf417

It's about Croatian characters: `ŠšĐđČčĆćŽž`
These are some of the characters I was able to map in ASCII:

Char code = Cro letter = How I see them in VS editor

```
196+144 = Đ = Ä
197+160 = Š = Å 
196+134 = Ć = Ä†
196+140 = Č = ÄŒ
```

Those characters (codes) my bank knows how to read and expects them to be in those codes. Is there a method or encoding that can do this automatically or is it a standard of sorts in my Country or EU...?
I doubt I should know and hardcode in my program those codes in order to be able to transport those characters in ASCII barcode PDF417. I can't find information about it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've found it. It is a HUB3 standard.
https://www.hub.hr/sites/default/files/inline-files/2dbc_0.pdf

[UTF-8 kodovi za Hrvatske dijakritičke znakove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrG2c.png)